# CSS to avoid transparent background for absolute position div

Tags: html, css

I have a div which hide/display on hover. The position set is absolute so background of div becomes transparent. If position set to relative then the parent div height is affected on hover. So how can the background made block so the content is not visible.

Need solution for css.
Sample given ->

```js
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#hover").hover(function() {
            $("#message").toggle();
        });
    });
```

```css
#message {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px #888888;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"id="hover" >Click Here</a>
<div id="message">
  <b>Hidden Content</b>
  <br/>This is a very large content which overlaps the content at background.<br/><br/>So the content in background should not be seen.
</div>
<div>This is another text whose content should be hidden under the popup.</div><br/>
<div>One more text added whose content is visible even if the hidden content is visible.</div>
```

Comment: `The position set is absolute so background of div becomes transparent` ??

Comment: Add Z-index and background-color to "#message"  - Eg. Z-index:9, Background-color:#fff

Comment: Background colour has nothing to do with absolute positioning, the default bg colour is transparent regardless of positioning.

Comment: `Need solution for css and without using jQuery.` ---> as a side note you are already using jQuery for a very simple CSS task

Comment: @TemaniAfif : I was trying Angular but it was not working over here. My project implementation is in AngularJs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have updated your code by adding Z-index and background-color. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```js
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#hover").hover(function() {
            $("#message").toggle();
        });
    });
```

```css
#message {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px #888888;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
z-index:9;
background:#fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"id="hover" >Click Here</a>
<div id="message">
  <b>Hidden Content</b>
  <br/>This is a very large content which overlaps the content at background.<br/><br/>So the content in background should not be seen.
</div>
<div class="setPosition">This is another text whose content should be hidden under the popup.</div><br/>
<div>One more text added whose content is visible even if the hidden content is visible.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a white background.

Also you can change the width accordingly

EDIT: You're already using jQuery =/

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $("#hover").hover(function() {
      $("#message").toggle();
    });
  });
```

```css
#message {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px #888888;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background: #FFF;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="hover">Click Here</a>
<div id="message">
  <b>Hidden Content</b>
  <br/>This is a very large content which overlaps the content at background.<br/><br/>So the content in background should not be seen.
</div>
<div>This is another text whose content should be hidden under the popup.</div><br/>
<div>One more text added whose content is visible even if the hidden content is visible.</div>
```